# ROS doesn´t run into NAO robot

Tags: ros, nao, cross-compiling, nao-robot, cross-compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using the newer Nao. I have installed ROS electric (desktop) over ubuntu 10.04 with the atom toolchain 1.12.5. Today it compiles onto the pc. Buuut, ROS still doesnt run over the NAO. I have copied all the ros files from pc to nao via ssh. I obtain that:

```
nao [0] ~/ros $ ls
electric  setup.sh

nao [0] ~/ros $ /home/nao/ros/setup.sh
-bash: /home/nao/ros/setup.sh: Permission denied

nao [err 126] ~/ros $ source /home/nao/ros/electric/setup.bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yaml
rospack could not be found, you cannot have rosbash features until you bootstrap ros

nao [0] ~/ros $ roscd
-bash: roscd: command not found

nao [err 127] ~/ros $
```

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43563/ros-doesn%C2%B4t-run-into-nao-robot./) by [LeonardoLeottau](https://answers.ros.org/users/3140/leonardoleottau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2012-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved.

```
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$TARGETDIR/libs:\\\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> $TARGETDIR/ros/setup.sh
echo "export PYTHONPATH=\\\$PYTHONPATH:$TARGETDIR/python" >> $TARGETDIR/ros/setup.sh
echo "source $TARGETDIR/ros/electric/setup.bash" >> $TARGETDIR/ros/setup.sh
```

Append at the top of file $TARGETDIR/ros/setup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
```

In a NAOś bash, run setup.sh

```
$TARGETDIR/ros
. ./setup.sh
```

---

Originally posted by [LeonardoLeottau](https://answers.ros.org/users/3140/leonardoleottau/) with karma: 58 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently, you are missing pyyaml. Install it and the error should disappear.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2